# Scanner JAVA certain requirements

Tags: java, string, int

For my code, I need to make a scanner which grabs user input for a school project of mine. However, the input can only be a 3 digit number or else it should prompt the user to ask for input again? How would I be able to do this with JAVA? Thanks.

This is what I currently have but it doesn't work

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(sc.nextInt() > 99 && sc.nextInt() < 1000) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

I currently have this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Everytime your call `sc.nextInt()` it will try again to take input from `System.in`.  Assign the value to an `int` variable and then test to see if the value is valid

Answer (score 3):

I would validate that you have an int in the scanner, before you try to assign it to an int variable. You can do that with the `Scanner.hasNextInt()` method.

Try out something like this, and see if it works for your application:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        while(input < 100 || input > 999) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a 3-digit number:");
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                input = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Always remember to close a `Scanner`, ***except*** a `Scanner` on `System.in`, in case `System.in` needs to be used again later.

Comment: Fair point, you would want to ensure that you're completely finished before closing the `Scanner`. So if you have more to do with this program then move the `scanner.close()` to a safe spot within your code.

Comment: Or simply don't close the `Scanner`. If you only want to close it when the program is done, there is no need to close it, since you no longer care about memory leaks at that point.

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the code to reflect the proper boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt()` will prompt you for input, so you should not use it in while condition.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
while(!(n > 99 && n < 1000)) {
    n = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int x;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 99 and less than 1000: ");
    x = in.nextInt();

    while (x >= 1000 || x <= 99) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number: Enter in range");
        x = in.nextInt();
    }

    in.close();

}
```